# Nor Flash File System with create variable amount of data file

Tags: file, system, stm32, flash-memory, nor

I had interfaced with STM32l0 Controller with my external serial nor flash MX25R in order to save a log file. Everything works fine during the operation like creating file, Writing and reading data. But my problem is that i am able to create a certain file size like 1024 for example:  `SerialFlash.create(SF_Name, 1024);_SF = SerialFlash.open(SF_Name);` I would like to create file like with variable amount of data as my file size may vary according to user setting. So may be some time 1 mb to 10 mb also. So how do i create this way of implementation? Thank you.

Comment: That sounds like a library and file system issue. Usually on FAT you can just append data and the file system will update the size. Not sure what you are using.

Comment: Hello @Flip , Thanks for the info I would like to provide you bit more information regarding my problem. I hereby paste the code i have no option to upload the file. **Library for using SPI Flash memory with a filesystem-like interface** [Library for using SPI Flash memory with a filesystem-like interface](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/SerialFlash).

Comment: Now as i mentioned above need to write data of size varible amount of data this is used for recording ADXL 345 readings: Sampling rate may be varied from 100-3200 samples pers second. I would like to create a file with out any size mentioned and at the time of closing the file need to check the size and read accordingly.

Comment: The issue is that is a limitation of the library that you are using. To quote: "Several limitations apply to writing. Only previously unwritten portions of the file may be written. File sizes can never change. Writes may only be done within the file's original size." Unfortunately I don't know of a better open source library at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @Flip for your reply and suggestion i had used SPIFFS and achived as mentioned above.